# sparse_tensor.values.numpy.tolist() shows error

Tags: tensorflow

getting error while executing this code

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
tf.executing_eagerly()
sparse_tensor.values.numpy().tolist()
```

After enabling the `eagerly(True)`, it still not giving desired output.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-c2bf1b7f6c3c> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sparse_tensor.values.numpy().tolist()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    441         np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
    442       """)
--> 443     self.__getattribute__(name)
    444 
    445   @staticmethod

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'.
```

Note: I am using TensorFlow 2.

Comment: Where did `sparse_tensor` come from? Apparently its `values` isn't actually an `EagerTensor`.

Comment: np_array=np.array([[1,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,2,0],
                   [0,0,0,4]])
sparse_tensor=tf.sparse.from_dense(np_array)
sparse_tensor
i have created a variable sparse_tensor

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you add your TF version?

Comment: 2.12.0
 i am using colab

Answer (score 0):

The code you have mentioned doesn't show any error when I tried replicating the same code in Google Colab using TensorFlow 2.12. Could you please rerun the code by opening a new notebook in Google Colab?

Please check the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: yes in Colab it is running.
thank you